# "Had been planning" or "were planning" What is the difference?

Tags: tenses, past-tense, past-perfect, perfect-aspect

> We_________(had been planning /were planning) to felicitate John at
>   our annual cultural fest when the news of his death______(had arrived
>   /arrived).

Can someone tell me which one to use and why, and why not?

Comment: See [this question] and its accepted answer for an idea of what the difference is.

Comment: What ***I*** would answer is "had been planning" ... "arrived". I don't know if that's one of the possible choices or not.

Answer (score -3):

Short answer: were planning / arrived

`had been planning` is past perfect continuous tense, which means the action had been happening a while before the moment of expressing it, which is not really the case in this sentence. Also, you would not use perfect tense where the exact time - `when the news arrived` - is specified, you should use simple (indefinite). We don't say `when the news had arrive` because past perfect is used to express the result/effect of some action available in the past, for example `He had arrived long before we started to gather`.

One more thing, `had been planning` implies some long-lasting action, while `planning to do something` is not such, it just means `thinking of doing something`. If it was `planning the annual cultural fest celebration` then it would make more sense to say `We had been planning the annual cultural fest celebration`. But in any case, if the time is specified you cannot use perfect tense:

- I had gone to school yesterday.
- I have done my homework 3 minutes ago.
- You had dropped your purse when you saw me.

All of these are incorrect and should be:

- I went to school yesterday.
- I did my homework 3 minutes ago.
- You dropped your purse when you saw me.

Comment: Isn't "had been planning"  past perfect continuous? But you said its past perfect?

Comment: Is it okay to write either had been planning or were planning in the same sentence with arrived itself

Comment: For an action that began in the past, continued, and then stopped in the past the [past perfect continuous tense](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verb-tenses_past-perfect-continuous.htm) is often used. "**I had been doing the gardening** all morning when some friends *turned up* unexpectedly. My hands *were* filthy, so I *ran* a hose quickly over my hands to get rid of the dirt and I *welcomed* my friends in."